# SOAP Web Service Decryption using AES & IV C# - Length of the data to decrypt is invalid

Tags: c#, web-services, encryption, soap, cryptography

I'm connecting to a web service within Visual Studio, I've got the parameters set up correctly, when triggered i get the error;

**Length of the data to decrypt is invalid**

This is due to Decryption, I have a AES key and IV not entirely sure how to apply this to the web service request.

AES Key: `RijndaelManaged Key = new byte[] { 0x1, 0x2... 0x16 };`

IV: `RijndaelManaged IV = new byte[] { 0x1, 0x2... 0x16 }`

I have checked a few threads about decryption, and from my findings they rely on creating the encryption to begin with. I have only been given the AES key and IV, ive been told its sufficient.

This is how I call the webservice;

`AWebService.BIServiceClient Client = new AWebService.BIServiceClient();`
`Client.getTransactions(true, username, password, Period, Year, MethodSignature, Database);`

Where would the decryption code go and how?

Comment: It sounds like you are supposed to encrypt the parameters you are sending. It is not completely clear, but I don't think you are supposed to decrypt anything, that is what is happening on the other end of the wire. Its trying to decrypt something that is not encrypted and failing.

Comment: I see, as part of the web service there is a feature that encrypts, it takes 1 parameter in the form of a string. Is the AES key an IV pointless in this scenario?

Comment: That's not what I mean. It's just an educated guess, but I think you are supposed to encrypt `password` (maybe others too) with that key and iv before calling `getTransactions`.

Comment: Post as an answer, that was all it was. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the service is trying to decrpt the data (parameters) you are sending to it, but you have not encrypted them.

Use the key and iv to encrypt the appropriate parameters before calling:

```
Client.getTransactions(true, username, password, Period, Year, MethodSignature, Database);
```

as an aside, if you have been trying to call a production service with un-encrypted data you have to assume the password is possibly compromised. Consider changing it.